# How to enable debug mode on Sony Xperia V with broken touch screen?

Tags: backup, usb-debugging, touchscreen, broken-screen

My Sony Xperia V touch screen is broken in the right corner. The rest of the screen doesn't respond, but the LCD works fine.

I need to make a full backup, but I can't activate debug mode. Also, Windows can't see the internal or external memory.

Do I have any other options on retrieving my data?

**UPDATE:** This problem is **SOLVED**. I got debug mode turned on by using a USB (Female) to Micro USB cable (Male). I connected a regular wireless mouse, and moused it through the settings.

Comment: Close, but not really, me touchscreen dont work, the LCD dos, but i got debug mode turned on by using a USB to Micro USB cabel, and connected a Wireless Mouse, and Moused it through the settings, never tried that before, but it worked perfectly.

Comment: @MikaelDipper Could you post your UPDATE as an Answer, and mark it as an answer later?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available for you.

- Given you have enabled USB debugging, you can [use Droid@Screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48490/23379) to view the android screen on your PC and control it. (So you can get backups through the PC)
- You can use an [otg](/questions/tagged/otg) adaptor to control your device using a USB mouse. (So that you can use whatever the app you want to back up your device)

Comment: Seems you have got the [tag:otg] option working.